# xpages errors after git merge

Tags: git, xpages, git-merge, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm working on an XPages project together with one other developer and we are using IBM Domino Designer 9.0. For source control we are using Git, Bitbucket and SourceTree.
I created a branch (branched off from Develop) to work with. When I was finish I switched to Develop, pulled from it's remote counterpart to get the other developer's changes. Then I merged my branch into develop - no merge conflicts occurred.
But when I'm opening the project in Designer i get lots of errors. E.g. when trying to open an XPage to work with I get this error:

Could not open the editor: Could not parse the .xsp-config file named CustomControls/entrySelector.xsp-config in the project C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\Data\workspace\DS8_2fD-D\customer_5cdtu_5ctrip.nsf

I have tried to delete the project and create a new one from the ODP but it doesn't work. Also the errors are changing. Sometimes it is able to open the XPage in Designer, but then it says that the Custom Control Tag isn't valid or something like that. Maybe it's worth mentioning that the files I'm working with has nothing what so ever to do with the entrySelector.xsp custom control file.

---

The problem just happened again. I was working on a feature branch and wanted to merge some changes from develop into that feature branch. I did the following:

Save and Clean/Build project
Sync with ODP
Stage all files:        SomeBean.java
                SomeBean.java.metadata
                editSomething.xsp
                viewSomething.xsp
                + 4 similar classes with other names
Commit all staged files
Checkout develop (switch from feature branch to develop)
Pull from origin/develop to develop
Checkout feature branch
Merge (from log) picked the latest commit from develop
ODP Refresh
Project.nsf sync with ODP
Clean and Build Project
BAAAM 9 Errors (the unknown tag xc:editSomething cannot be used as a control)

Maybe it's worth mentioning that none of the files above was new/untracked. They were also present in the develop branch.
When I try to open the editSomething.xsp I now get this error message:
Could not open the editor: An unexpected exception was thrown

This problem has kinda become somewhat of a daily struggle and it pisses me off as I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check the affected files in the ODP for non-XML content. Perhaps the merge (or some other merge) added merge markers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have checked the affected files in the ODP, but nothing seems to stand out.I guess that somehow I'm not using Git and GitFlow the correct way

Comment: OK, then use Package Explorer and check if the affected .xsp-config file in your nsf looks corrupted. Also look for duplicate files.

Comment: I checked all affected files in the ODP but found nothing unusual. I've just solved the problem by associating the ODP with new NSF. When the association was made and a new database created, this (new) project contained zero errors. Then I associated the ODP with the "old" project again and everything is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this go into Package Explorer and right-click a blank area and select refresh. Then in source tree, see if there are any uncommitted changes. If there are I bet they're xsp-config files. Select them, right click and select discard.

If that doesn't work, still check your uncommitted changes and discard them (if you haven't made any changes). In Designer, right-click your nsf and select Team Development\Associate with existing on disk project (or something to that effect). Select the proper on disk project and select the import option.

If none of that works, find the offending xsp-config files and copy/paste from the SCM web site. While not elegant it will get you around this very frustrating issue.

While this is kind-of a convoluted process I've found that one of the above processes will usually fix the issue.

**EDIT:** I wanted to post this yesterday but I couldn't find the setting I was looking for. But in DDE Preferences, navigate to General\Workspace and check "Refresh Automatically". This setting has stopped this issue from happening for us but your mileage may vary.

Comment: The first two of your solutions didn't work. I haven't tried to copy/paste any xsp-config files yet since they don't seem to be corrupted this time. I have added a description of this (slightly different) problem to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this issue a couple of times. Not quite sure why. We are investigating it yet to see if we can re-create it.

However, we have found a way to get back on track with the code. First we tried to create a new NSF based on the ODP. That worked. So then we re-associated the original NSF with the ODP - and that brought it back to a state where we could edit the design elements again ;-)

/John

Comment: By the way. We have seen the problem on 9.0 - and so far I believe it must be a problem in DDE. I am therefore upgrading to 9.0.1 right now to try and solve the issue - but we still don't know exactly how to re-create the problem....